# issues randomly populating a 2d array of structure type in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, random

I'm trying to populate a 20x20 matrix where each entry is of structure type. My goal is to randomly assign 100 ants and 5 doodlebugs on this 2D array. Even though I got it to work, I don't always get the amount of ants or doodlebugs I need in the matrix. I added a counting function to always verify how many of them I have each time I run the program, but I'm always slightly short. I'm trying to force those number to work (100 ants and 5 doodlebugs) by using a `do`/`while` loop in my populating function, although it's not working. Can someone spot where is my logic is failing me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 20

struct cellState {
    int emptyInt;
    int antInt;
    int dBInt;

    char emptyChar;
    char antChar;
    char dBChar;
};

struct cellState gridState[N][N];

// function to populate world
void pop_mtx(struct cellState gridState[N][N], int antsNeeded, int dBNeeded) {
    int i, j;

    do {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {    
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if ((gridState[i][j].emptyInt = rand() % 3) == 0) {
                    gridState[i][j].emptyChar = '.';
                } else
                if (((gridState[i][j].antInt = rand() % 3 == 1) && antsNeeded != 0)) {
                    gridState[i][j].antChar = 'a';
                    antsNeeded--;
                } else
                if (((gridState[i][j].dBInt = rand() % 3 == 2) && dBNeeded != 0)) {
                    gridState[i][j].dBChar = 'D';
                    dBNeeded--;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (dBNeeded != 0 && antsNeeded != 0);
}

//function to display current state of the world
void display_mtx(struct cellState gridState[N][N]) {
    int i, j;
    char charToDisplay;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (gridState[i][j].antChar == 'a')
                charToDisplay = 'a';
            else
            if (gridState[i][j].dBChar == 'D')
                charToDisplay = 'D';
            else
                charToDisplay = '.';

            printf("%c  ", charToDisplay);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

//function to count ants and doodlebugs
void count_mtx(struct cellState gridState[N][N]) {
    int i, j, antCount = 0, dBcount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (gridState[i][j].antChar == 'a')
                antCount++;
            else
            if (gridState[i][j].dBChar == 'D')
                dBcount++;
        }
    }
    printf("ant count: %i, doodlebug count: %i\n", antCount, dBcount);
}

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    //populate grid state with 5 doodlebugs and 100 ants
    int antsNeeded = 100, dBNeeded = 5;
    pop_mtx(gridState, antsNeeded, dBNeeded);

    count_mtx(gridState);
    display_mtx(gridState);
}
```

Comment: Your population logic doesn't look right. A couple of issues but the main one is that once an entry has been populated with an Ant or DB, there is nothing in the code to prevent it from being overwritten later with something else (due to the outer `do` loop). And theoretically the outer loop can be infinete because there is no guarantee that the condition to exit will ever be met due to the randomness of the algorithm (in practice it will end but still not a good algorithm IMHO).

Comment: So I took out the do while and used and if statement in the case that the condition (dBNeeded!=0 || antsNeeded!=0) was met. I also added an else to the else-if loop with a (continue;). And that seemed to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems. First, each time you call rand() you obtain a different value, so it is possible that none of the three tests pass. You should call rand () once and save the value.

Second, there is nothing that guarantees that over NxN calls of rand() you will get as many ones and twos as you need. The outer loop is therefore necessary. You should also preserve already populated squares from one iteration to the next because it might take a long time before you reach an iteration that produces enough ones and twos.

Third, this method is biased toward the squares at the beginning of the grid. It will not give you one out of all possible distributions of 100 ants and 5 doodlebugs over 400 squares with equal probability.

Here is the proper way to do it:

Consider the grid as a uni-dimensional array. First fill it, in order, with 100 ants, 5 doodlebugs, and empty spaces. Then perform a [random shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) of the array.

This procedure will return each possible distribution of the ants and doodlebugs on the grid with equal probability.